# FCM Notification not receive in foreground using xamarin forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been integrating push notification using firebase in Xamarin. I have created developer provisioning profile and also generated P12 file and attach in Firebase console project.

I am sending notification from cloud messaging(From FCM Console project), the notification receives when the app is closed, if I started the app then send a notification, the notification not receive.

This is Firebase initialisation

```
     LoadApplication(new App());

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                                        (granted, error) =>
                                                                        {
                                                                            if (granted)
                                                                                InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                                                                        });
            }
            else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                        new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            else
            {
                UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
            }

//FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(launchOptions,true);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
```

In my case fist condition is true (if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))) and notification registration successfully

and the RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method called every time when I debug the app

When i send notification from cloud messaging the **DidReceiveRemoteNotification** callled but notification not show(comes)in foreground if application closed(background) notification comes

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken, FirebaseTokenType.Sandbox);
    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

    }
    // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
    // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
        // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
        // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }

    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        base.ReceivedRemoteNotification(application, userInfo);
    }



    // To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 10 devices.
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine(notification.Request.Content.UserInfo);
    }


    public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(remoteMessage.AppData);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest something helpful?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the push notification behavior whenever your app is in background then only device receives push notifications.

Comment: hello @KiShOrE this DidReceiveRemoteNotification method not call when app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved issue that not received notification in `Foreground`.
I implemented a class `NotificationDelegate` then inherit this class by `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`
After that create methods for handle notification in Foreground iOS 10

```
 public class NotificationDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
   {
    public NotificationDelegate()
    {
    }

    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        // Do something with the notification
        Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);

        // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
        // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert|UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
    }


    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        // Take action based on Action ID
        switch (response.ActionIdentifier)
        {
            case "reply":
                // Do something
                break;
            default:
                // Take action based on identifier
                if (response.IsDefaultAction)
                {
                    // Handle default action...
                }
                else if (response.IsDismissAction)
                {
                    // Handle dismiss action
                }
                break;
        }
        completionHandler();
    }
  }





I am facing this issue(not receive notification in foreground) because in WillPresentNotification method i am sending only UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert (completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);) but both alert and sound are required for notification in Foreground and Background in iOS 10
```

Then did code for register notofication in server

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter center = UNUserNotificationCenter.Current;

                center.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge, (bool arg1, NSError arg2) =>
                {
                    if (arg1)
                        InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);

                });

                center.Delegate = new NotificationDelegate();
            }
            else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {

                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);

            }

            return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
        }
```

Then create registration method in AppDelegate class

```
 public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken, FirebaseTokenType.Sandbox);
        }
```

The important think if you using `Debug Mode` in this case

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken, FirebaseTokenType.Sandbox);
```

and in Entitlements.plist add this

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

if you using `Release Mode` in this case

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken, FirebaseTokenType.Production);
```

and in Entitlements.plist add this

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

For devices running iOS 9 and below, override AppDelegate's DidReceiveRemoteNotification method to handle notifications received when the client app is in the foreground, and all data messages that are sent to the client. A message is a dictionary of keys and values:

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
   // Do your magic to handle the notification data
   System.Console.WriteLine (userInfo);
}
```

For iOS 10 devices and above, implement IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate interface and override WillPresentNotification method to handle notifications received when the client app is in the foreground:

```
// To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 10 devices.
[Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
{
  // Do your magic to handle the notification data
  System.Console.WriteLine(notification.Request.Content.UserInfo);
}


 public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(remoteMessage.AppData);
}
```

Comment: Hello @hakim i am facing new issue, i  implemented IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate interface then first time notification receive in both are `forground and background` but in second time debug notification not receive in both are `forground and background`

Comment: You might wanna check out iOS local notifications and create your own with code!! https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/local-notifications-in-ios-walkthrough&ved=2ahUKEwiKha6YkPDjAhXt6XMBHd-xD4YQFjAAegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw17kd8gcuZl5TfLne1YdOFt

Comment: @FreakyAli Bro.  I can receive notifications in my xamarin.ios app. But DidReceiveRemoteNotification   never hits. My os vesion is 12.4.1 . Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673761/fetch-firebase-push-notification-data-without-clicking-notification-xamarin-fo?noredirect=1#comment110925087_62673761