# Fetch Firebase push notification data without clicking notification - Xamarin.forms iOS

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hi I have a xamarin forms ios application implemented with firebase push notifications. I can receive and mange the click of notifications. Currently I am trying to  store the notification data ie; `Title,body and two other parameters` comes with notification in to sqlite database. I can retrieve and store the data when user clicks. But cant store if user swipe away the notification. How can I get the values as soon as notification appear? Any help is appriciated.

```
My AppDelegate


  [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
    {     
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {           
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();    
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            LoadApplication(new App());
     
            //<-------Firebase Implementation------------->

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                //Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
            }

            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
            Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;


            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        //<--------Firebase Portion------->

        [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
        public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
        {       
            Settings.FirebaseRegID = fcmToken;
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "fcmtoken", fcmToken.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine($"fcmtoken received: {fcmToken}");
        }

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {         
            HandleMessage(userInfo);        
            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveRemoteNotification), userInfo);
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);                  
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState.Equals(UIApplicationState.Active))
            {
                //App is in foreground. Act on it.  
            }
            else
            {
                // MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<key>>(this, "messagedata", myData);
            }
        }

        //User for showing the notification in foreground mode
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification,
        Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
        }

        //Foreground mode notification tapping handling here
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action
        completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler();
            NSDictionary userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;           
            try
            {               
                var Data = userInfo[new NSString("gcm.notification.data")] as NSString;
                if (Data != null && Data != "")
                {
                    string[] tokens = Data.ToString().Split(',');
                    string Username = tokens[0];
                    string Password = tokens[1];
                    var Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Notification.Request.Content.Title)?"No Notification available": response.Notification.Request.Content.Title;
                    var Body = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Notification.Request.Content.Body)?"No Message available": response.Notification.Request.Content.Body;        
                    MessagingCenter.Send(new NotificationData() { TItle = Title.ToString(), Body = Body.ToString(),username= Username ,Password= Password }, "iosnotificationTapped");                 
                }       
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        [Export("messaging:didReceiveMessage:")]
        public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
        {
            // Handle Data messages for iOS 10 and above.
            HandleMessage(remoteMessage.AppData);
            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveMessage), remoteMessage.AppData);
        }

        void HandleMessage(NSDictionary message)
        {
            //if (MessageReceived == null)
            //    return;

            //MessageType messageType;
            //if (message.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
            //    messageType = MessageType.Notification;
            //else
            //    messageType = MessageType.Data;

            //var e = new UserInfoEventArgs(message, messageType);
            //MessageReceived(this, e);
        }

        public static void ShowMessage(string title, string message, UIViewController fromViewController, Action actionForOk = null)
        {
            var alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (obj) => actionForOk?.Invoke()));
            fromViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void LogInformation(string methodName, object information) => Console.WriteLine($"\nMethod name: {methodName}\nInformation: {information}");  
    }
```

**EDIT**  I tried to put debugger on

```
void DidReceiveRemoteNotification,void DidReceiveMessage,void HandleMessage
```

None of them hit when notification appears. Only `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` will hit if we tap the notification. In android there is **onmessagereceived** which will hit when notification arrives. Does iOS have such method?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217194/discussion-on-question-by-anand-fetch-firebase-push-notification-data-without-cl).

Comment: Have you checked debugger to `DidReceiveMessage` ? I get this hit whenever message received.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat Yes bro I checked. It doesnt hi too.  But WillPresentNotification will hit. and  DidReceiveNotificationResponse will also hit when we tap notification

Comment: Try to add this line in your `FinishedLaunching` `Firebase.Core.App.Configure();` try to make your code same as mine `FinishedLaunching` may be there is something you're missing.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat Does data only messages have any role in this issue? Should I make it data only?

Comment: May be but you should try with `Notification Payload only`, `Data Payload only` and in last with both payloads.